# Django :How to integrate Django Rest framework in an existing application?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How should I integrate Django-REST-API framework in an existing application or I have to create a new project?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You do not need to begin a new project. The basic steps are:

1. Install DRF, something like `pip install djangorestframework`
2. Add `rest_framework` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`
3. Define your serialisers, views and routes.

And that's it.

I suggest you follow the [Quickstart](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart) and step through the [Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization) — it's pretty welcoming really.

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1, this is the simplest way, btw, if you are worried about performance and you need some granularity I would separate both the web project and the API project and give the needed priorities to each of them. For example, if your API will be used much more than your web, use more resources to serve your API.

Answer (score 19):

I created a short note about how to do this with the photo gallery app tutorial from the Forcier et. al. book.  I'm a Django noob, so please take this stuff as not-authoritative-perhaps-not-even-good.  Here's the link to the post:

https://technote.fyi/blog/2018/01/26/how-to-add-rest-api-existing-django-project/

Basically, you create a new app, then in it write code for only three files: serializers.py, views.py, and urls.py. You don't write anything in models.py.  Instead, you import the models from the existing app.

You then start off by creating serializers for all the models you want to expose, and then views for those serializers, and, finally, urls to call those views.

Comment: You are fantastic! Thank you

Comment: I believe there's no more pdf in the link. Could you update if you will? Thank you!

Comment: The link you have shared doesn't have any pdf.

Comment: Link has been updated and the PDF has been found and attached.