# How to convert my current django app to REST API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I need to convert my current django app which is a UserCreationForm with email and phone numbers validation to a REST API. But first I need to register the text fields to the django admin site to have the phonenumber, email and password fields. However in my admin.py at "admin.site.register(UserRegisterForm)", when I run python manage.py makemigrations, an error occurred and it states TypeError: 'ModelFormMetaclass' object is not iterable. I'm not sure if maybe the admin.site does not accept the fields in any UserForms and they only accept models.
Here is my code:

```
/* forms.py */
import re
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from validate_email import validate_email
# from django.db import models
# from django_countries.fields import CountryField, countries
# from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    # phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    # country = CountryField(blank_label='Select Country').formfield()
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'country', 'phone_number']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email

    def clean_phone_number(self):
        phone_number = self.cleaned_data.get("phone_number")
        clean_number = re.sub("[^0-9&^+]", "", phone_number)
        # alpha_2 = self.cleaned_data.get("country")
        alpha_2 = self.cleaned_data.get("country")
        z = phonenumbers.parse(clean_number, "%s" % (alpha_2))
        if len(clean_number) > 15 or len(clean_number) < 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Number cannot be more than 15 or less than 3")
        if not phonenumbers.is_valid_number(z):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Number not correct format or non-existent")
        if carrier.name_for_number(z, "en") == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a mobile number")
        return phonenumbers.format_number(
            z, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)


/* admin.py */
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

admin.site.register(UserRegisterForm)
# Register your models here.
```

Please tell me what changes should be made to my current code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `admin.site.register` is for models, not forms. It's not at all clear what you want to do, and what this has with a REST API.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that you can't really 'convert' a form (front-end component) to a REST-API (back-end interface). That's like asking a hair-dresser to cut your hair longer with scissors.

But.. You can use your models.py in a new django-REST-project.

SUGGESTION:

- Start a new django project and add the desired apps (using the django
  cli).

***install django rest*** (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation)

- `pip install djangorestframework` and add ('django_rest') to installed apps
  (settings.py)
- Copy your code from the model.py into the model.py of your new app
- Create a (model) serializer (that checks all the data goin I/O the model)
- Create views for every endpoint (this is your interface)
- run `python manage.py makemigrations`
- run `python manage.py migrate`
- You now have a working rest-api!!

At last: Your admin site enables you to (visually) interact with your models and its data. It's meant for the admin of your website and it doesn't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that the title of your question doesn't fit with the description. You wrote that you want to convert your current Django App into an API then you detailed in your description that there's an issue with your form loading inside the admin site.

Nevertheless, I found this article that's very close to the answer by [@Ewald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58216651/21240810). It really helps me to **Convert my current Django project into a Rest API**. Of course, we have to reformulate our Views and URLs but keep the rest untouched (models.py, admin.py...), don't really need to do anything there.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24402271/21240810) help me. Hope it helps others too who come to this question.