# benefit of Django REST Framework when using django with API like calls?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

reading [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402017/django-how-to-integrate-django-rest-framework-in-an-existing-application/24402271) it looks like I can setup DRF within an existing django project.

That got me thinking... I have a django application that uses ajax calls which return very simple view partials which quickly display on the page, and then a few seconds later another ajax call is made to return another view.  (you can think of it like the Whac-a-mole games, but each mole is a different view partial being returned from the server.)

so essentially I have 30-50 calls per minute to `mysite.com/ajax_new_mole` with a view similar to *(just made this up on the fly, ignore any errors)*

```
...
def ajax_new_mole(request):
  random_id = get_random_mole_id()
  random_mole = Mole.objects.get(id = random_id)
  return render(request, 'partials/_mole_photo.html, {'mole':random_mole})
...
```

and the `_mole_photo.html` template

```
{% load load_cloudfront %}
<div class="img-wrapper" id="{{ photo.id }}">
  <span class="album-title" id="album-title">Title: {{ mole.name }}</span>
  <img src='{% load_cloudfront_medium mole.name %}' id="image{{ photo.id }}"/>
</div>
```

Now to my question.  In this situation.  Would Django REST Framework offer any performance benefits in **the reduced overhead** for responding to and rendering this content?

Comment: DRF is just based on the basic django requests build up with alot more functions easier to handle everything that an API need, so since it's an extension the speed efficiency would be not as fast as normal django request because DRF also use rendering when returning result so i would say it's slower. There an interesting article on testing speed of DRF which is [here](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/api-performance-profiling-django-rest-framework/) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The bottleneck of the DRF is in Serializers. So the hardest part is for serializing the model and deserializing the request. That's why if you are using it only for this type of small snippet, then I would not suggest using DRF. You'd better use it only if you have more than 10 API views.

Comment: I have updated @Pynchia, sorry, I have written in a rush and that was the reason.